# Scrolldown image in tableView bit slow

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with customCell which displays three images in each row.When i scroll down or up it is taking little bit time to move up or down even though i resized image.I have loaded images from folder.

Comment: if you are using [UIImage imageNamed:@""], then dont use that

Comment: instead of that what else can i use?

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: You should cache the image before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because u are fetching all the images at the time of scrolling and scrolling gets slower.

You should use **SDWebImage classes**, [heres link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) that uses caching schemes to load those images whose rows are there to be shown on UITableView